# Increment data based on previous entry

Tags: mysql

How would you make this kind of database. My system holds one database with multiple users (companies) whom make offers for customers.

What i can't figure is how i can insert data to database so offer_nr increments +1 from previous increment of company_id?

```
+----+--------- +------------+----------+
| offer_id (AI) | company_id | offer_nr | 
+----------+----------+----------+
|  1            | 1001       | 10022    |
|  2            | 1002       | 150      |
|  3            | 1001       | 10023    |
|  4            | 1002       | 151
+----+------------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a before update trigger.  You would use such a trigger to assign the value of `offer_nr` based on the historical values.  The key code would be:

```
new.offer_nr = (select coalesce(1+max(offer_nr), 1)
                from offers o
                where o.company_id = new.company_id
               )
```

You might also want to have `before update` and `after delete` triggers, if you want to keep the values in order.

Another alternative is to assign the values when you query.  You would generally do this using a variable to hold and increment the count.

Answer (score -1):

Don't make it this way.

Have autoincremented company ids as well as independent order ids.
That's how it works.

There is no such thing like "number" in database. Numbers appears only at the time of select.

Comment: No, i have different table for Companies where i get this company_id and different table for Offers where i get offer_id. I just wan't to have offer_nr to be 10024 for next insert of company_id 1001

Comment: YES you have to have different table for Companies. NO, there is no point in numerating orders this way.

Comment: Can you give me example of tables how you would do this? Because each customer want to have different numbering on their invoices and offers etc...

Comment: Nope, they don't need that.